# How to skip a filter in spring filter chain?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http

I want to skip a filter - FilterSecurityInterceptor as it throws `No AuthenticationProvider found`  exception. Can we skip a specific filter from spring chain?

Once I call my custom filter, I do have `chain.doFilter(request, response);// return to others spring security filters` in my code which returns to other spring security filters. How do I make sure the FilterSecurityInterceptor is not being verified.

Here is my custom filter code

````
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        Authentication authResult;
        String domainUser = request.getHeader(USER_ID);
        String signature = request.getHeader(SIGNATURE);
        String token = request.getHeader(SECURITY_TOKEN_KEY);
        if (domainUser == null || domainUser.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Exception("Please provide the Domain User");
        }
        if (signature != null && !signature.isEmpty()) {
            authResult = signatureVerification.verifySignature(signature, domainUser);
            if (authResult == null) {
                logger.info("Unauthorized access attempted: HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED");
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                return;
            }
        } else if (token != null && !token.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                authResult = attemptAuthentication(request, response);
                if (authResult == null) {
                    logger.info("Unauthorized access attempted: HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED");
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                    return;
                }
            } catch (AuthenticationException failed) {
                logger.info("Unauthorized access attempted: HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED");
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                return;
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Please provide either auth token or signature");
        }

        try {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            if (e.getCause() instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
                logger.info("Unauthorized access attempted: HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED");
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                return;
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);// return to others spring security filters
    }


and this is are the configure methods in SecurityConfiguration class

```  @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/webjars/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                csrf().disable().
                sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).
                and().
                authorizeRequests().
                anyRequest().authenticated().
                and().
                anonymous().disable().
                exceptionHandling().
                authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint());
        http.addFilterBefore(new TokenAuthenticationFilter(tokenService(), getSignatureVerification()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(domainUsernameTokenAuthenticationProvider()).
                authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider()).
                authenticationProvider(domainUsernameTokenAuthenticationProvider());
    }
````

Comment: Why you want to remove `FilterSecurityInterceptor `? 
If you don't need security, then just get rid of `spring-security` dependency

Comment: The reason for trying to skip FilterSecurityInterceptor is, it throws org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found  exception. All the other filters do work fine except for the last one.

Comment: Please look at the https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider
You should create your own implementation for  `AuthenticationProvider` instead of skipping filter